# Using egrep but starting to think awk or sed might be the solution

Tags: awk, sed, grep, posix

First, I am using Cygwin mintty 2.7.4 so... posix. I have mutliple snippets of code exist in a file similar to the following:

```
<blah>Spread the peanut butter <ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="2 or 6"/> on good looking bread <ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="3 or 5"/> that does not have peanut butter <ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="2 or 6"/> already on the bread this that and the other <ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="4"/> with something else.</blah>
```

I am trying to find duplicate instances of the ramout tag inside a set of blah tags. 
If the following exists:

```
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="2 or 6"/>
```

I want to know if it is repeated again within a set of opening and closing blah tags.

I've tried multiple things. One of the latest was the following:

```
grep -Eoi '<blah>.*([[:space:]]<ramout assot).*\1.*</blah>' *.xml | less
```

which returned nothing.

I also tried:

```
 grep -Eio '<blah>.*([[:space:]]<ramout assot="[a-z][0-9]{5}_fig[0-9]+" bapel="[0-9]+.*)' *.xml
```

which does not include the backreference which nets results but does not show all results. It looks like this is only showing the results that are one line/do not span across a more than one line.

Should I use sed if I want to search for something that may or may not be on one line?

Is awk a viable candidate? I saw and tried: awk '/Start pattern/,/End pattern/' filename which returned more results but I am still not getting all results.

Any help being able to find a) all ramout results in the entire file and separately b) all ramout results that are duplicates within blah tags would be appreciated.

Expected results would look something like:

results for search a) showing all ramout results:

```
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="2 or 6"/>
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="3 or 5"/>
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="2 or 6"/>
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="4"/>
```

results for search b) showing duplicate results would show:

```
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="2 or 6"/>
```

Comment: `a)` and `b)` seems to be separate tasks. Show how should look the expected result

Comment: Good point. Expected results added above. Thank you.

Comment: If this xml don't use sed or awk.  Use a tool that understands xml parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse/query XML/XHTML documents use one the following tools:

- *xmlstarlet*
- *xmllint*
- *saxon-lint*

---

I'll suggest the solution using `xmlstarlet`.
**1)** Install `xmlstarlet` tool
**2)** Use *XmlStarlet* `select` or `sel` option to query or search *XML* documents ([***xmlstarlet manual***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html))

---

**a)** all `<ramout>` tags in the entire file:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -n  -m "//blah/ramout" -c "." -n testfile.xml
```

The output:

```
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="2 or 6"/>
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="3 or 5"/>
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="2 or 6"/>
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="4"/>
```

---

**b)** all `<ramout>` tags that are duplicates within `<blah>` tags:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -n  -m "//blah/ramout" -c "." -n testfile.xml | sort | uniq -d
```

The output:

```
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="2 or 6"/>
```

---

`uniq -d`:
 `-d, --repeated` - only print duplicate lines, one for each group

Comment: Thank you. Awesome... was not familiar with xmlstarlet. Will be very helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**a)** `sed 's/</\n</g;s/>/>\n/g' pb.txt | sed -n '/<blah/,/<\/blah/{/ramout/p}'`

The first sed invocation just ensures line breaks around tags.  The second invocation prints every `ramout` line between `blah` tags.  The syntax is `/START/,/END/{/MATCH/p}` meaning from START to END, print lines that MATCH.

So you get this:

```
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="2 or 6"/>
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="3 or 5"/>
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="2 or 6"/>
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="4"/>
```

As the xmlstarlet answer established, you can then pipe that to `sort` and then `uniq -d`:

**b)** `sed 's/</\n</g;s/>/>\n/g' pb.txt | sed -n '/<blah/,/<\/blah/{/ramout/p}' | sort | uniq -d`

For this output:

```
<ramout assot="f0123_fun10" bapel="2 or 6"/>
```

+1 to the xmlstarlet answer as it's the proper way to do things, and established `sort | uniq -d`.  If you know this sort of sed syntax, though, you've got a hammer and everything looks like a nail.

Comment: Thank you. Trying to learn more sed so this will be very useful.

Comment: @regexnoob No problem.  Shoot this answer a +1 when you've got the rep